# Reducing ng-model boilerplate code (DRY)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Using `ng-model`, the sign in form in our app has ended up looking something like this:

```
<form name="signIn" ng-submit="ctrl.signIn()" novalidate>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{'invalid': signIn.email.$invalid && (signIn.$submitted || signIn.email.$touched)}">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="ctrl.email" required>
    </label>
    <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="signIn.email.$error" ng-if="signIn.$submitted || signIn.email.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="app/common/form-messages.html"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{'invalid': signIn.password.$invalid && (signIn.$submitted || signIn.password.$touched)}">
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="ctrl.password" required>
    </label>
    <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="signIn.password.$error" ng-if="signIn.$submitted || signIn.password.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="app/common/form-messages.html"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive">
            <b>Sign In</b>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This feels *very* repetitive to me.  In a form with more than two inputs, this code would become quite overwhelming.

I'm an experienced developer, but new to Angular.  **What's the "Angular way" for reducing this boilerplate?**

Specifically:

- Every `<label/>` element will have essentially the same `ng-class` attribute of the form `{'invalid': signIn.<field_name>.$invalid && (signIn.$submitted || signIn.<field_name>.$touched)}`.
- Every `<label/>` element will be followed by essentially the same `<div class="form-errors"...>` element.  Similar to above, the only difference will be the field referenced.

As I try to "think in Angular" (especially with an eye toward Components), it seems that the best approach would be to make each `<label></label><div class="form-errors"></div>` pair a directive.  I would simply need to pass into the directive the various attributes to use for each `<input/>` element (e.g. `name`, `type`, `placeholder`, `ng-model`, and `ng-model` validators (e.g. `required`)).

**Is this the recommended "Angular way" to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you, the angular aproach would be to create a directive for that or if you use Angular 1.5+ a component.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing! Thanks for confirming that I'm on the right path! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Good to see people care about DRY ;-)